# How to send message only to a specific cars in veins?

Tags: omnet++

In venis demo each node send message to all nodes. However, i want to send message only to nodes that is located in a specific road ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically a message is always received by all nodes. If you want to send only to specific nodes you can filter the received messages. For example you can get the current road from the `Vehicle` in the `TraCICommandInterface.h` with the [`getRoadId()`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/mobility/traci/TraCICommandInterface.h#L46) function.

This can then be attached to a message and on receiving a message just compare the nodes current road with the one from the message. If the node is another road, just ignore the message, if it is on the correct road process the message.

Comment: I would  be grateful if you could  show me the class and the code that i must  change it  to make this filter please ?

Comment: In [`TraCIDemo11p`](https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/traci/TraCIDemo11p.cc#L50) you can see the position where - for example something can be done. Or you write your own application based on (`BaseWaveApplLayer`)[https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/master/src/veins/modules/application/ieee80211p/BaseWaveApplLayer.h]. The method `handleLowerMsg` can be modified for example.

Comment: Thank you so much  floxyz for your answer